# JWT authentication ignoring Lockout settings?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, jwt, bearer-token

I'm playing around with Identity and JWTs based on based on [dualauthcore](https://github.com/shawnwildermuth/dualauthcore), and have tested getting a user locked out.   I could not do it by attempting to log in with an incorrect password, and also not by including invalid tokens in the header.

```
  options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
  options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;
  options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
```

Is there a way to get JwtBearer authentication to obey Identity's lockout settings, or is JwtBearer authentication just free of such concerns?

Answer (score 1):

JWT can be revoked, so next time you log in lockout will kick in. 
Lockout is a log in/sign in process concept. After logging in you can get your token for authN/authZ activities.

Comment: Thanks, the code I'm looking at has a GenerateToken method:
[link](https://github.com/shawnwildermuth/DualAuthCore/blob/master/DualAuthCore/Controllers/AccountController.cs). 
You can POST endless emailaddess/password combinations to it.   It seems that to address my concerns, the 
if (result.Succeeded) - clause should be followed by an else, where fails are handled.

Comment: There should be lockoutOnFailure: true as far as I see in PasswordSignIn

Comment: That is it! Thanks.

Comment: but how jwt can be revoked if you don't store it?